# calculating numbers from dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

on releasing key i'm trying to calculate the numbers entered in text fields.
Converting them into integers i want to get them calculated found multiple ways here to do this problem. e.g

> Note: This snippet below is example i have take it from somewhere on stackoverflow i'm not trying to do this, my fields are dynamic in jquery

```js
$(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />

    <input type="text" class="total" value="" />
```

But the problem here is my fields are coming dynamic using jquery, http://sageaccountants.biz/forms/smsf-with-individual-trustee/  and i'm using wordpress so i have little limited access to form i have add classes through jquery first and by some customization i have managed to make a "result" div just below "beneficiary appointed by member1".
Here is my code what i have done so far:

```
var count = 0;
jQuery(".gf_repeater_add").on("click", function(){
jQuery("#input_59-1-"+count).addClass('member1');
if(count == 10)
{
count = 0;
}
});
jQuery(document).on("change", ".medium", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    jQuery(".medium").each(function(){
        sum += +jQuery(this).val();
    });
    jQuery(".total").val(sum);
});

<input name="input_59-1-1" id="input_1_59-1-1" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="25" aria-invalid="false" data-repeater-inputid="1">
```

on pressing "+" icon there could be more fields and my method on adding class by id doesn't seem to work here. i'm doing

```
jQuery(".gf_repeater_add").on("click", function(){
jQuery("#input_59-1-"+count).addClass('member1');
if(count == 10)
{
count = 0;
}
});
```

but it doesn't add class in single one or in dynamic one

Comment: extra quote in there...you can see it in the syntax highlighting ...`+count+"` should just be `+count`. Use your browser console to check for errors thrown

Comment: You have an unnecessary `A`: `$(".qty1").each(function(){A`, other than that your code seems to work.

Comment: i didn't have any error in console, and that wasn't my code i have take it from somewher on stackoverflow and it was working there don't know what `A` was doing there :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

You are trying to dynamically add a class **`member`** to a bunch of elements that have ids like **`input_59-1-*`** when the user clicks another element with class as **`gf_repeater_add`** in the document.

You want a dynamic handler (I say dynamic because the element on which it is supposed to run doesn't yet exist till you click the above mentioned element) on `document` that adds all the numbers from the selected fields that have class as **`member`** and puts the total into another input box.

See the demo in below.

```js
console.log("Demo");
$(".gf_repeater_add").on("click", function(){
   console.log("Adding 'member' class to all the input boxes");
   for (var count=0; count<3; count++) {
      $("#input_1_59-1-"+count).addClass('member');
   }
});

$(document).on("change", ".member", function() {
   console.log("Adding data from all input boxes");
   var sum=0;
   $(".member").each(function(){
       if ($(this).val()!=="") {
           sum += parseInt($(this).val());
       }
   });
   $("#total").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="gf_repeater_add">Make boxes addable</button>
<input id="input_1_59-1-1" type="text" value="" class="medium"/>
<input id="input_1_59-1-2" type="text" value="" class="medium"/>
<br><br>Result:
<input id="total" type="text" value="" class="medium"/>
```

Comment: omg, yes that's exactly what i want so you have made another button which fix this functionality, one thing only can we do it without clicking on box ?

Comment: In that case, you don't need to add class to those input boxes. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the 'A' (pointed out by other posts here). I added parseInt to avoid adding with NaN. I changed the jQuery select to .qty1 itself (may be that was optional).

```js
$(".qty1").on("change", function() {
   sum=0;
   $(".qty1").each(function() {
       myval=$(this).val();
       if (myval==="") return;
       sum += parseInt($(this).val());
       console.log("Sum is: "+sum);
       $(".total").val(sum);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />

    <input type="text" class="total" value="" />
```

Comment: I thought your problem was the code in first post. I am trying to understand your subsequent question. Is it safe to say that your jQuery code is adding a class attribute to one of the DOM elements and you are trying to get to that DOM element? I will read through your second para again in few minutes and respond to you.

Comment: yea that's what i'm saying. people read my first para only and removed a typo and answered it. well i was saying something different than that which you have just pointed

Comment: okay i worked in console and typed my code there and it seemed to work there

Comment: Good. Sometimes it gets tricky because we try to add elements based on an event and add handlers to those elements (that are still not there when the document loads). Sometimes, the handlers get removed if you don't handle them in correct sequence. Good that now it is working for y ou.

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to your question, "Can we do it without clicking on another button". I wrote this code, so that you can refer back to the other answer if you still want to.

If you don't need the click, you don't need the button, you don't need to add class to the input elements. You could write a handler on all input elements by pattern matching on their id. See the following demo.

```js
$("*[id^=input_1_59-1-]").on("change",function() {
   console.log("Adding data from all input boxes");
   var sum=0;
   $("*[id^=input_1_59-1-]").each(function(){
      if ($(this).val()!=="") {sum += parseInt($(this).val());}
   });
   $("#total").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="input_1_59-1-1" type="text"/>
<input id="input_1_59-1-2" type="text"/>
<input id="input_1_59-1-3" type="text"/>
<input id="input_1_59-1-4" type="text"/>
<br><br>Result:
<input id="total" type="text"/>
```

Comment: nevermind the answer i accepted work perfect, so i'm sticking with that. Thanks that was such a great help saves my time and teaches me bit more jquery

Comment: hi there @blackpen couldn't thank you enough for the help your solution is rocking on the site. i should do enough jquery to help others now :)

Comment: i think i need your help again, its bit relative if you could look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274630/copy-address-by-dynamic-check-boxes-in-dynamic-fields it has the explanation . thanks