# copy address by dynamic check boxes in dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

My site's one of form has address fields, 4 in total.
 
now what i'm trying to do is when user input address details there are dynamic option given to user by which user can generate new "Address" fields dynamically.
By each generation of address fields there is dynamic "checkbox" option too, so i was trying to do work with it like if user clicks that checkbox the first entry user made should gets copied to the newly fields user created dynamically.
So how do i achieve that ? so far i have done it like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    alert('jqyert working');


     //these are fields user entered at first
      var address    = jQuery('#input_1_5_1').val();
      var address_2  = jQuery('#input_1_5_2').val();
      var state      = jQuery('#input_1_5_4').val();
      var region     = jQuery('#input_1_5_5').val();
      console.log(address+" "+address_2+" "+state+" "+region);

    jQuery('*[id^=choice_15_74_1-2-]').change(function(){
    jQuery("*[id^=choice_15_74_1-2-]").each(function(){

     if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {

     alert('check box got hit');
     //this alert doesn't even run

      jQuery('*[id^=input_15_22_1-2-]').val(address);
      jQuery('*[id^=input_15_22_2-2-]').val(address_2);

      jQuery('*[id^=input_15_22_4-2-]').val(state);
      jQuery('*[id^=input_15_22_5-2-]').val(region);

    }
    });

    });

    });

    </script>
```

why does the second block doesn't work ?

***********************************EDIT**********************************

> Fields from where i want my data to be copied

```
<div class='ginput_complex ginput_container has_street has_street2 has_state has_zip ginput_container_address gfield_trigger_change' id='input_15_5' >
   <span class='ginput_full address_line_1' id='input_15_5_1_container' >
       <input type='text' name='input_5.1' id='input_15_5_1' value='' tabindex='4'  />
       <label for='input_15_5_1' id='input_15_5_1_label' >Street Address</label>
    </span><span class='ginput_full address_line_2' id='input_15_5_2_container' >
        <input type='text' name='input_5.2' id='input_15_5_2' value='' tabindex='5'  />
        <label for='input_15_5_2' id='input_15_5_2_label' >Address Line 2</label>
        </span><span class='ginput_right address_state' id='input_15_5_4_container' >
        <input type='text' name='input_5.4' id='input_15_5_4' value='' tabindex='8'    />
        <label for='input_15_5_4' id='input_15_5_4_label' >State / Province / Region</label>
   </span>
   <span class='ginput_left address_zip' id='input_15_5_5_container' >
         <input type='text' name='input_5.5' id='input_15_5_5' value='' tabindex='9'  />
         <label for='input_15_5_5' id='input_15_5_5_label' >ZIP / Postal Code</label>
    </span>
         <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='input_5.6' id='input_15_5_6' value='Australia'/>
  <div class='gf_clear gf_clear_complex'></div>
```

> Fields to where i want my data to be copied (Note: these fields are dynamic, checkbox are dynamic too)

```
<input name='input_67.1' type='checkbox'  value='Same as first address'  id='choice_15_67_1' tabindex='18'  />
        <label for='choice_15_67_1' id='label_15_67_1'>Same as first address</label>
        <label class='gfield_label gfield_label_before_complex' for='input_15_12_1' >Address</label>    
          <div class='ginput_complex ginput_container has_street has_street2 has_state has_zip ginput_container_address gfield_trigger_change' id='input_15_12' >
               <span class='ginput_full address_line_1' id='input_15_12_1_container' >
               <input type='text' name='input_12.1' id='input_15_12_1' value='' tabindex='19'  />
               <label for='input_15_12_1' id='input_15_12_1_label' >Street Address</label>
               </span>
               <span class='ginput_full address_line_2' id='input_15_12_2_container' >
               <input type='text' name='input_12.2' id='input_15_12_2' value='' tabindex='20'  />
               <label for='input_15_12_2' id='input_15_12_2_label' >Address Line 2</label>
               </span>
               <span class='ginput_right address_state' id='input_15_12_4_container' >
               <input type='text' name='input_12.4' id='input_15_12_4' value='' tabindex='23'    />
               <label for='input_15_12_4' id='input_15_12_4_label' >State / Province / Region</label>
               </span>
               <span class='ginput_left address_zip' id='input_15_12_5_container' >
               <input type='text' name='input_12.5' id='input_15_12_5' value='' tabindex='24'  />
               <label for='input_15_12_5' id='input_15_12_5_label' >ZIP / Postal Code</label>
               </span>
               <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='input_12.6' id='input_15_12_6' value=''/>
             <div class='gf_clear gf_clear_complex'></div>
```

Apart from this code here is the live site form on which i have run this code: http://sageaccountants.biz/authority-to-set-up-a-family-trust/

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for error reports or used it for debugging?

Comment: No error in console. You should show your html for us to know the checkbox set also!

Comment: okay actually the form is coming from a wordpress plugin but let me show that html

Comment: @NewToJS and antoni please look at the edit i have made, plus i have also attached the live site link. I couldn't see any error in console that's why i am unable to get what's wrong with this code is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet most closely matches with what you are trying to do in your website. It acts on the ID patterns provided in the "Settler Details". Every time, the user clicks the "(+)" link, it registers the event handlers on all the new checkbox elements.

The only part that is not present in this code is "creating address block dynamically". I mock-tested that part to make sure that it falls in place. Also you may want to find better IDs for the fields for "First Address".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function register_eventhandlers() {

   /* Handler on checkboxes.
      When checkbox is selected, find it's parent LI iterm,
      navigate to it's sibling element (address block).
      Populate the input fields in the address block.
   */
   jQuery("[data-repeater-inputid][id*='choice_'][type='checkbox']").change(function(){
      console.log("Inside checkbox handler - 1");
      if (jQuery(this).prop('checked')) {
         console.log("Checked is selected");
         var addr_block=jQuery(this).closest("[data-repeater-childid][data-repeater-repeatid][data-repeater-parentid].gfield").next();
         if (addr_block) {
             console.log("Address Block (LI) found");
             console.log(addr_block);
         }

         var gform      = jQuery("form[id^='gform_']");
         var gform_body = gform.find(".gform_body");
         var inputs     = jQuery("form[id^='gform_'] > .gform_body input");
         var address_1  = inputs.eq(2).val();
         var address_2  = inputs.eq(3).val();
         var state      = inputs.eq(4).val();
         var region     = inputs.eq(5).val();

         console.log("gform:"); console.log(gform);
         console.log("gform_body:"); console.log(gform_body);
         console.log("inputs:"); console.log(inputs);
         console.log("Address Fields="+address_1+":"+address_2+":"+state+":"+region);

         addr_block.find("[data-repeater-inputid='1']").val(address_1);
         addr_block.find("[data-repeater-inputid='2']").val(address_2);
         addr_block.find("[data-repeater-inputid='3']").val(state);
         addr_block.find("[data-repeater-inputid='4']").val(region);
      }
   });
}

function register_observer() {
   var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
   var myObserver       = new MutationObserver (mutationHandler);
   var obsConfig        = { childList: true, characterData: true, attributes: true, subtree: true };

   console.log("Inside register_observer");
   jQuery(".gform_body").each (function(){ myObserver.observe (this, obsConfig);});
   function mutationHandler(mutationRecords){
      console.log("Observer called");
      register_eventhandlers();
   }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   register_observer();
   register_eventhandlers();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <li id="field_15_95" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below">
        <label class="gfield_label gfield_label_before_complex" for="input_15_95_1">Address</label>
        <div class="ginput_complex ginput_container has_street has_street2 has_state has_zip ginput_container_address gfield_trigger_change" id="input_15_95">
            <span class="ginput_full address_line_1" id="input_15_95_1_container">
                <input name="input_95.1" id="input_15_95_1" value="" tabindex="50" type="text"/>
                <label for="input_15_95_1" id="input_15_95_1_label">Address:</label>
            </span>
            <span class="ginput_full address_line_2" id="input_15_95_2_container">
                <input name="input_95.2" id="input_15_95_2" value="" tabindex="51" type="text"/>
                <label for="input_15_95_2" id="input_15_95_2_label">Suburb:</label>
            </span>
            <span class="ginput_right address_state" id="input_15_95_4_container">
                <input name="input_95.4" id="input_15_95_4" value="" tabindex="54" type="text"/>
                <label for="input_15_95_4" id="input_15_95_4_label">State / Province / Region</label>
            </span>
            <span class="ginput_left address_zip" id="input_15_95_5_container">
                <input name="input_95.5" id="input_15_95_5" value="" tabindex="55" type="text"/>
                <label for="input_15_95_5" id="input_15_95_5_label">ZIP / Postal Code</label>
            </span>
            <input class="gform_hidden" name="input_95.6" id="input_15_95_6" value="" type="hidden"/>
            <div class="gf_clear gf_clear_complex"/>
        </div>
    </li>

  <li data-repeater-childid="2" data-repeater-repeatid="2" data-repeater-parentid="2" id="field_15_74-2-2" class="gfield copy-input_1_5_1-to-input_1_12_1 field_sublabel_below field_description_below gf_repeater_child_field">
    <label class="gfield_label"/>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_checkbox">
      <ul class="gfield_checkbox" id="input_15_74">
        <li class="gchoice_15_74_1">
          <input data-repeater-inputid="1" name="input_74.1-2-2" value="Same as first address" id="choice_15_74_1-2-2" tabindex="29" type="checkbox"/>
          <label for="choice_15_74_1-2-2" id="label_15_74_1">Same as first address</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li whatever="1" data-repeater-childid="3" data-repeater-repeatid="2" data-repeater-parentid="2" id="field_15_22-2-2" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gf_repeater_child_field">
    <label class="gfield_label gfield_label_before_complex" for="input_15_22_1-2-2">Address</label>
    <div class="ginput_complex ginput_container has_street has_street2 has_state has_zip ginput_container_address gfield_trigger_change" id="input_15_22">
      <span class="ginput_full address_line_1" id="input_15_22_1_container">
        <input data-repeater-inputid="1" name="input_22.1-2-2" id="input_15_22_1-2-2" value="" tabindex="29" type="text"/>
        <label for="input_15_22_1-2-2" id="input_15_22_1_label">Street Address</label>
      </span>
      <span class="ginput_full address_line_2" id="input_15_22_2_container">
        <input data-repeater-inputid="2" name="input_22.2-2-2" id="input_15_22_2-2-2" value="" tabindex="29" type="text"/>
        <label for="input_15_22_2-2-2" id="input_15_22_2_label">Address Line 2</label>
      </span>
      <span class="ginput_right address_state" id="input_15_22_4_container">
        <input data-repeater-inputid="3" name="input_22.4-2-2" id="input_15_22_4-2-2" value="" tabindex="29" type="text"/>
        <label for="input_15_22_4-2-2" id="input_15_22_4_label">State / Province / Region</label>
      </span>
      <span class="ginput_left address_zip" id="input_15_22_5_container">
        <input data-repeater-inputid="4" name="input_22.5-2-2" id="input_15_22_5-2-2" value="" tabindex="29" type="text"/>
        <label for="input_15_22_5-2-2" id="input_15_22_5_label">ZIP / Postal Code</label>
      </span>
      <input tabindex="29" data-repeater-inputid="5" class="gform_hidden" name="input_22.6-2-2" id="input_15_22_6-2-2" value="" type="hidden"/>
      <div class="gf_clear gf_clear_complex"/>
    </div>
  </li>


  <li data-repeater-childid="2" data-repeater-repeatid="3" data-repeater-parentid="2" id="field_15_74-2-3" class="gfield copy-input_1_5_1-to-input_1_12_1 field_sublabel_below field_description_below gf_repeater_child_field">
    <label class="gfield_label"/>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_checkbox">
      <ul class="gfield_checkbox" id="input_15_74">
        <li class="gchoice_15_74_1">
          <input data-repeater-inputid="1" name="input_74.1-2-3" value="Same as first address" id="choice_15_74_1-2-3" tabindex="29" type="checkbox"/>
          <label for="choice_15_74_1-2-3" id="label_15_74_1">Same as first address</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-repeater-childid="3" data-repeater-repeatid="3" data-repeater-parentid="2" id="field_15_22-2-3" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gf_repeater_child_field">
    <label class="gfield_label gfield_label_before_complex" for="input_15_22_1-2-3">Address</label>
    <div class="ginput_complex ginput_container has_street has_street2 has_state has_zip ginput_container_address gfield_trigger_change" id="input_15_22">
      <span class="ginput_full address_line_1" id="input_15_22_1_container">
        <input data-repeater-inputid="1" name="input_22.1-2-3" id="input_15_22_1-2-3" value="" tabindex="29" type="text"/>
        <label for="input_15_22_1-2-3" id="input_15_22_1_label">Street Address</label>
      </span>
      <span class="ginput_full address_line_2" id="input_15_22_2_container">
        <input data-repeater-inputid="2" name="input_22.2-2-3" id="input_15_22_2-2-3" value="" tabindex="29" type="text"/>
        <label for="input_15_22_2-2-3" id="input_15_22_2_label">Address Line 2</label>
      </span>
      <span class="ginput_right address_state" id="input_15_22_4_container">
        <input data-repeater-inputid="3" name="input_22.4-2-3" id="input_15_22_4-2-3" value="" tabindex="29" type="text"/>
        <label for="input_15_22_4-2-3" id="input_15_22_4_label">State / Province / Region</label>
      </span>
      <span class="ginput_left address_zip" id="input_15_22_5_container">
        <input data-repeater-inputid="4" name="input_22.5-2-3" id="input_15_22_5-2-3" value="" tabindex="29" type="text"/>
        <label for="input_15_22_5-2-3" id="input_15_22_5_label">ZIP / Postal Code</label>
      </span>
      <input tabindex="29" data-repeater-inputid="5" class="gform_hidden" name="input_22.6-2-3" id="input_15_22_6-2-3" value="" type="hidden"/>
      <div class="gf_clear gf_clear_complex"/>
    </div>
  </li>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i saw a anonymous jquery code it may have anything to do with preventing action on checkboxes ? should i try with radio buttons?

Comment: Does the code fails to find the checkboxes? OR does it fail to detect the checkboxes as "selected"?

Comment: i'm getting response in console

Comment: well not really at first there were some "$" reference error after getting it fixed now i get response when ever i click checkbox, i'm pasting one of them e.g
`[li#field_15_12-1-1.gfield.field_sublabel_below.field_description_below.gf_repeater_child_field.gfiel…, selector: "", prevObject: a.fn.init[1], context: input#choice_15_67_1-1-1]`

Comment: i get around 8 object array in the console with messages `Checked is selected
(index):493 Address Block (LI) found`

Comment: I saw your website just now. You seem to have succeffully copied the address fields from settler to beneficiary. Good work.

Comment: well it's all your credit, but i'm still missing the very frist block to be copied :( the very first block is missing

Comment: You mean the IDs of the first address block have been hard-coded? I will take a look and let you know.

Comment: when we press "+" icon the event got fired up and then it works all fine, but take a scenario when user doesn't create new fields and yet try to copy the address into those fields, in that case it isn't copying

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready()` calls `register_eventhandlers()` which sets up handlers for all pre-existing **(+)** icons. If/when you click a **(+)** icon (which creates more address blocks), then the `register_observer()` gets called, which calls `register_eventhandlers()`, which will set up handlers for all pre-existing and **as well as** new **(+)** icons on the page. If you think the `register_observer()` is not working, you could put a `console.log` statement in it and test, I guess. I just tested it to be working. May be you fixed the problem?

Comment: Just in case you want to have better anchors for the input fields in the first address block, I added the new anchors to the above code.

Comment: thanks well your knowledge is overwhelming me, checking it very quickly wont help me :p will be telling after implementation. Thanks alot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127070/discussion-between-habib-rehman-and-blackpen).

Answer (score 1):

When the checkbox is clicked, the first address (four fields) should get copied to the second address (four fields).

Since you may not have fine-grained control over generated `id/name/class` fields in html, my solution may/mayn't be suitable for your need. Try it and see.

I didn't change html. I only changed code inside your `$jQuery(document).ready()` call.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#choice_15_67_1").change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("[name='input_12.1']").val($("[name='input_5.1']").val());
            $("[name='input_12.2']").val($("[name='input_5.2']").val());
            $("[name='input_12.4']").val($("[name='input_5.4']").val());
            $("[name='input_12.5']").val($("[name='input_5.5']").val());
        }
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class='ginput_complex ginput_container has_street has_street2 has_state has_zip ginput_container_address gfield_trigger_change' id='input_15_5' >
    <span class='ginput_full address_line_1' id='input_15_5_1_container' >
    <input type='text' name='input_5.1' id='input_15_5_1' value='' tabindex='4'  />
    <label for='input_15_5_1' id='input_15_5_1_label' >Street Address</label>
    </span><span class='ginput_full address_line_2' id='input_15_5_2_container' >
    <input type='text' name='input_5.2' id='input_15_5_2' value='' tabindex='5'  />
    <label for='input_15_5_2' id='input_15_5_2_label' >Address Line 2</label>
    </span><span class='ginput_right address_state' id='input_15_5_4_container' >
    <input type='text' name='input_5.4' id='input_15_5_4' value='' tabindex='8'    />
    <label for='input_15_5_4' id='input_15_5_4_label' >State / Province / Region</label>
    </span>
    <span class='ginput_left address_zip' id='input_15_5_5_container' >
    <input type='text' name='input_5.5' id='input_15_5_5' value='' tabindex='9'  />
    <label for='input_15_5_5' id='input_15_5_5_label' >ZIP / Postal Code</label>
    </span>
    <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='input_5.6' id='input_15_5_6' value='Australia'/>
    <div class='gf_clear gf_clear_complex'></div>
    <input name='input_67.1' type='checkbox'  value='Same as first address'  id='choice_15_67_1' tabindex='18'  />
    <label for='choice_15_67_1' id='label_15_67_1'>Same as first address</label>
    <label class='gfield_label gfield_label_before_complex' for='input_15_12_1' >Address</label>    
    <div class='ginput_complex ginput_container has_street has_street2 has_state has_zip ginput_container_address gfield_trigger_change' id='input_15_12' >
        <span class='ginput_full address_line_1' id='input_15_12_1_container' >
        <input type='text' name='input_12.1' id='input_15_12_1' value='' tabindex='19'  />
        <label for='input_15_12_1' id='input_15_12_1_label' >Street Address</label>
        </span>
        <span class='ginput_full address_line_2' id='input_15_12_2_container' >
        <input type='text' name='input_12.2' id='input_15_12_2' value='' tabindex='20'  />
        <label for='input_15_12_2' id='input_15_12_2_label' >Address Line 2</label>
        </span>
        <span class='ginput_right address_state' id='input_15_12_4_container' >
        <input type='text' name='input_12.4' id='input_15_12_4' value='' tabindex='23'    />
        <label for='input_15_12_4' id='input_15_12_4_label' >State / Province / Region</label>
        </span>
        <span class='ginput_left address_zip' id='input_15_12_5_container' >
        <input type='text' name='input_12.5' id='input_15_12_5' value='' tabindex='24'  />
        <label for='input_15_12_5' id='input_15_12_5_label' >ZIP / Postal Code</label>
        </span>
        <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='input_12.6' id='input_15_12_6' value=''/>
        <div class='gf_clear gf_clear_complex'></div>
```

Comment: first of all thanks for coming to this post,
and isn't it just for single field ? what do we do for dynamic fields ? if user makes 3,4,5 address fields that's why i used regular expressions

Comment: Is there a button somewhere in the screen, upon clicking which, the user can create as many addresses as he wants? If so, could you show the pattern of ids for those fields for more than two addresses (so that we can generalize)?

Comment: http://sageaccountants.biz/authority-to-set-up-a-family-trust
yes this is the form and it has option to copy address fields with checkbox

Comment: Ok, then. You see that you have a **(+)** image which when clicked calls _`gfRepeater_repeatRepeater();`_. I assume that, that code is out of your reach for modifications. If so, you could try to navigate the DOM tree to reach the select checkbox that was just added and add an event handler to the button (which is cumbersome but efficient). Another way is just to use the DOM listener I mentioned and run it on the "form" that you have (instead of "body" as I suggested).

Comment: yes it's wordpress plugin and code is certainly out of reach. so it's like the DOM you mentioned with listener will reach the check box after it's being created. right ?

Comment: Yes. If you hook the DOM listener to "body", it will get called everytime there is a change in the generated html. Still, we need to get a relation between the pattern of IDs of checkbox and the IDs of the corresponding address fields. Otherwise, we will end up populating wrong address fields (somewhere else in the document). If you have already figured out the relation, you can substitute that in your code using the **match** function on attribute (ID).

Comment: yes i have already figured that out, i'll looking into the match function to get it done

Answer (score 1):

(After reading your comment "what do we do for dynamic fields?")

1) Your IDs seem to be different in js-code vs html-code. I modified js-code to make them match.

2) You are trying to read addresses before the user types them in, thus they have no values in them, yet. I moved them into a event handler so that we read values only when the user selects the checkbox.

3) You are trying to register event handlers on address fields, even before the corresponding html elements are actually created. Do you have a button, by clicking which, the user gets to create new addresses? If so, you could also call my "register_eventhandlers" immediately after creating the said new addresses.

4) Since, I am not sure if "creating new addresses" is under your control, I wrote a `register_observer` (not a nice way of doing things) to listen to changes in DOM and register event handlers on-the-fly. If you use this method (instead of the button mentioned above), you may want to listen on mutation events on a specific `div` rather than do it inefficiently on `body` as I have done.

5) I am not sure what is a pattern in the IDs generated. If you know the pattern, you can modify the patterns in js-code.

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function register_eventhandlers() {
     var address_1  = jQuery('#input_15_5_1').val();
     var address_2  = jQuery('#input_15_5_2').val();
     var state     = jQuery('#input_15_5_4').val();
     var region    = jQuery('#input_15_5_5').val();
     console.log(address_1+" "+address_2+" "+state+" "+region);

         jQuery("*[id^='choice_15_67_1']").change(function(){
            jQuery("*[id^='choice_15_67_1']").each(function(){
               if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
                  alert('check box got hit');
                  jQuery("*[id^='input_15_12_1']").val(address_1);
                  jQuery("*[id^='input_15_12_2']").val(address_2);
                  jQuery("*[id^='input_15_12_4']").val(state);
                  jQuery("*[id^='input_15_12_5']").val(region);
               }
            });
         });
      }

      function register_observer() {
            var MutationObserver   = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
            var myObserver        = new MutationObserver (mutationHandler);
            var obsConfig         = { childList: true, characterData: true, attributes: true, subtree: true };
            $("body").each ( function () {
                  myObserver.observe (this, obsConfig);
            } );
            function mutationHandler(mutationRecords) {
                  console.info ("mutationHandler");
                  register_eventhandlers();
            }
      }

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         register_eventhandlers();
         register_observer();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: well yes i don't have control over the repeating of fields. and shouldn't we use it like `*[id^='input_15_12_1-']` this ?